# Not able to return JSON objects from server to client after successful file upload

Tags: jquery, express, typescript

I have a project that uses NodeJS + Express + JQuery + Typescript. I am uploading a file from the front end which happens successfully. However I'm not able to return a JSON object back from the server to the client which contains the location of the object on the server.
When the JSON data returns to the client it actually renders (the JSON) on the screen instead of being received by the `"success: function (response)"` function on the client side.

Here's the client side code:

```
function sendFile() {

    $(new ID().setAsRoot().selectId()).append(
        "<form id=\"fileUploadForm\" accept-charset=\"utf-8\" method=\"post\" action=\"/upload\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">" +
            "<input id = \"filename\" type=\"file\" name=\"userfile\" multiple=\"multiple\" />" +
            "<button type=\"submit\"> Upload </button></form>");

    var $form = $("#fileUploadForm");
    $form.submit(function (e) {

        alert("Upload Started");
        // perform client side validations if any

        this.ajaxSubmit({
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            },

            success: function (response) {
                alert("Success " + JSON.parse(response));
            }
        });

        // Important: stop event propagation
        return false;
    });
}
```

Here's the server side code:

```
app.post('/upload', function(request, response){
    var upload = new uploadModule.Upload();
    upload.upload(request, response);
});


    public upload(req:express.Request, res) {
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        var originalFileName:String;
        var filePath:String;
        form.uploadDir = this.directory;
        form.keepExtensions = true;
        form.type = 'multipart';
        var fields = [];
        form
            .on("error", function (err) {
                //res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
                //res.end('error:\n\n' + util.inspect(err));
            })
            .on("field", function (field, value) {
                //console.log(field, value);
                //fields.push([field, value]);
            })
            .on("end", function () {
                //console.log('-> post done');
                //res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
                //res.end('received fields:\n\n ' + util.inspect(fields));
                res.send({
                    path : filePath,
                    name : originalFileName
                });
            })
            .on("file", function(name, file:formidable.File){
                originalFileName = file.name;
                filePath = file.path;
            });
        form.parse(req);
        return;
    }
```

--- Update ---

I see these errors in the Chrome console, and I don't know what they mean:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : shortcut_manager.js:123
(anonymous function) shortcut_manager.js:123
(anonymous function) extensions::messaging:327
Event.dispatchToListener extensions::event_bindings:386
Event.dispatch_ extensions::event_bindings:371
Event.dispatch extensions::event_bindings:392
dispatchOnMessage extensions::messaging:294
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o Server.ts:21
$.ajax.success Server.ts:21
c jquery.js:3048
p.fireWith jquery.js:3160
k jquery.js:8235
r jquery.js:8778
```

I am using the JQuery form plugin for file uploads and the js file of the plugin doesn't seem to be downloaded in Chrome. I am also using require JS, in which I heve included the form plugin.

```
require(["//malsup.github.io/min/jquery.form.min.js"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your descriptions it seems, that no AJAX call is made but the form is uploaded normally. ajaxSubmit() is not a standard jQuery function. Do use some jQuery-plugin? Is the plugin loaded?

Comment: I am using "JQuery Form Plugin". You can find it here: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object

Comment: And is it included correctly? Did you check you console in the browser for a Javascript error?

Comment: Aha! Thats the problem. The plugin is not downloaded. I've updated the question.